# How many different versions of Barbie are featured in the “Barbie” movie?

Tags: character, barbie

In the recent *Barbie* (2023) movie, how many different versions of Barbie are featured?

I'm interested in the diversity of characters and roles they represent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Here are all 18 Barbies in the *Barbie* (2023) movie via Screen Rant:](https://screenrant.com/how-many-barbies-are-there-movie-real-life/)

> 1. Teen-age Fashion Model
> 2. Stereotypical Barbie
> 3. President Barbie
> 4. Weird Barbie
> 5. Writer Barbie
> 6. Physicist Barbie
> 7. [Midge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midge_(Barbie))
> 8. Doctor Barbie
> 9. Lawyer Barbie
> 10. Judge Barbie
> 11. Mermaid Barbie
> 12. Journalist Barbie
> 13. Diplomat Barbie
> 14. Barbie Video Girl
> 15. Growing Up Skipper
> 16. Teen Talk Barbie
> 17. Skipper
> 18. Proust Barbie